# Facebook PHP SDK Session conflict with Yii CWebUser

Tags: facebook, session, yii, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently developing a Facebook canvas app, which has multiple tabs, using the Yii framework.
And there is a  problem in setting the **CWebUser** component for the app.
I'm setting the `user` component in `SiteController`'s `actionIndex()` method.
After setting that, i want to redirect to a particular page tab within my app.
In the redirected page, i want to use the user info, but the user component info is lost.
The code for the SiteController is below:

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller{
 // other functions

  public function actionIndex(){ 
   // call the Facebook PHP SDK to getUser();
   $fbHelper = new FacebookHelper();
   $userInfo = $fbHelper->getCurrentInfo();
   Yii::app()->user->setId($value['id']);
   Yii::app()->user->setName($value['name']);
   // further i set some more values that are required by the app using setState()
   // query the db to find out what the user was doing last time
   // and then redirect accordingly to the next page
   $this->redirect(array('pagelist/index'));
  }
}
```

The code for the new page:

```
<?php
class PagelistController extends Controller{
 public function actionIndex() {
  $this->render('index');
 }
}
```

The code in the index.php view for PagelistController:

```
<?php
 echo "Hi ".Yii::app()->user->name;
 // Yii::app()->user->getIsGuest(); returns true, which shouldn't be the case.
```

So obviously the user info is getting lost in the redirection.
Now what i gather is, that Facebook's PHP SDK is using sessions to store its instance, and so does the CWebUser component. So my guess is that the FB PHP SDK is clearing the session on redirects, which also ends up clearing the Yii app session. Or something close to that is happening!!
So then how do we persist the user info during the application's lifetime?
Should i be modifying the FB PHP SDK, so that it uses the already generated session  of the yii app? Or maybe prevent it from clearing the session on redirects?
Appreciate any help.
**Edit :** 
I was using sessions with the code below, included in the main.php configuration file, as an application component. However if this code is removed everything works fine, any ideas as to why this prevents the session retention?

```
'session'=>array(
        'sessionName'=>'PageType',
        'autoStart'=>true,
        'cookieMode'=>allow,
        'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
        'connectionID' => 'db',
        'sessionTableName' => 'tbl_session',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following extension which is created for facebook connect...

https://github.com/ielshareef/FacebookExtension4Yii

I found it useful and until now there is no problem.. Even i've updated the latest version of PHP-SDK and made some changes according to my nature..

This extension uses the userIdentity interface to set the current logged in facebook to the default CWebUser ...

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look. Just looked, at first glance, this is what i noticed : "Once the user is authenticated, his/her information will be stored in Yii::app()->session['facebook_user']."

Comment: So i wanted to access using `Yii::app()->user->getName();` and etc, but even then this might be helpful, so thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CWebUser::setState()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail) to update the session instead of Yii::app()->user->setName, e.g.:

```
$cwu = new CWebUser();
$cwu->setState('name','newname');
```

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a try. But $cwu won't be available in the next controller, and its views, right? Do you however have any idea on how to merge my yii app session with the Facebook sdk session?, i have no idea about this, not even sure i'm asking the right question.

Comment: hi, i have located why my problem was occurring, i have added a piece of code in the question. Can u check my **edit** and gimme a few pointers, please?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflict between facebook API session and Yii session you should edit the file **facebook.php** and, inside the constructor, **replace**

```
if ((function_exists('session_status') && session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) || !session_id()) {
      session_start();
    }
```

by

```
if ((function_exists('session_status') && session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) || !session_id()) {
  Yii::app()->session->open();
}
```